# How to convert a list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list with multiple lists inside it like below:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
```

But want to convert the same into dictionary and make first element of each array as key value like below

```
x = [(1:2,3),
 (3:4,5),
 (6:7,8)]
```

Comment: I changed "directory" to "dictionary". I believe that is what you meant. *However*, your output is *not* a dictionary. It looks like a list of tuples (with invalid syntax)

Comment: What should be 1:2, 3:4 and 6:7 ?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{l[0]:l[1:] for l in x}
```

This loops through the list and takes the first element of each nested list as the key and the rest as the value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your description of a dictionary is correct, and the code sample you have displayed above is incorrect:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
y = {}
for i in x:
    y[i[0]] = i[1:]
print y
# {1: [2, 3], 3: [4, 5], 6: [7, 8]}
```

If what you wanted was a list of tuples:

```
tuple([tuple(i) for i in x])
```

If it's a dictionary that you wanted to check for membership, and to print the last element

```
if 1 in y:
    print y[1][-1:]
else:
    print 'Not Found'
```

Comment: thanks for reply
it gave me the exact ans which i wanted 
but i have one more condition in this 
if 1 is in y then
it should print print 3
means 2nd value of its list
else print not found
how to do that plz help

Comment: You will benefit from reading https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html. Just check for membership and print the last element?    

    if 1 in y:
        print y[1][-1:]
    else:
        print 'Not Found'

Comment: @pradeeppawar, and if you specifically want the second element, use y[1][2] instead of y[1][-1]. Anyway I have updated the answer to include this extra bit that you want